# How to set z-index using relative and absolute position properties?

Tags: html, css

I'm facing problem using `z-index` for relative and absolute position properties, below `orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdownInner` is child div of  `orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdown`. `z-index` is working as expected but I have scroll bar on the page when I scroll horizontal `orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdownInner` div also change the position. How can I keep position where it should be normally even using horizontal or vertical scroll?

**CSS:**

```
.orcitMultiselectTreeviewPosition .orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdown .orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdownInner {
    position: relative;
    z-index:999999;
}    
 .orcitMultiselectTreeviewPosition .orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdown {
     position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Vertical (Y-axis) and Horizontal (X-axis) positions have nothing to do with `z-index` (Z-axis). If you want it to stay put even during scrolling, you want to position it with `position: fixed`.

Comment: position:fixed is setting outiside the parent div

Comment: Can you better describe your expected behavior? My understanding is that you want to the inner div to stay in the same position even during a page scroll.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements don't share a z-index with other non-absolutely positioned elements.  Also I don't see what your question has to do with z-index.

Comment: originally my z-index was off for child element i was able to fix that with above code but now child position is not changing with scroll

Comment: @gfullam inner div should stay with parent div when scroll

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to position elements on top of each other using z-index, **all parent elements of the child element that has a defined z-index, must also have defined z-indexes**. Z-indexing positions things "on top of each other," as you seem to know, but it only works on child-parent interactions. (Doesn't matter if child or parent div is the one "in front" or "behind")

2) Try `position:absolute;` for both OR try positioning `.orcitMultiselectTreeviewDropdownInner` with `left:0; top:0;` or something

3) Try `z-index:999;` for one and `z-index:99` for the other